# Unable to create files in $HOME directory using user_data

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I've always been puzzled why I cannot create files in $HOME directory using user_data when using an aws_instance resource. Even a simple "touch a.txt" in user_data would not create the file.

I have worked around this by creating files in other directories (e.g. /etc/some_file.txt) instead. But I am really curious what's the reason behind this & if there is a way to create files in $HOME with user_data.

Thank you.

----- 1st edit -----
Sample code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "ubuntu" {
  ami = var.ubuntu_ami
  instance_type = var.ubuntu_instance_type
  subnet_id = aws_subnet.ubuntu_subnet.id
  associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  key_name = var.key_name
  vpc_security_group_ids = [aws_security_group.standard_sg.id]
  
  user_data = <<-BOOTSTRAP
#!/bin/bash
touch /etc/1.txt          # this file is created in /etc/1.txt
touch 2.txt               # 2.txt is not created in $HOME/2.txt
                BOOTSTRAP

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.project}_eks_master_${count.index + 1}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, I'd argue that if you know the user you will log in with you also know the home directory. I understand your point, but I think the solution is simple.

Comment: What is your TF code?

Comment: Edited my question to include sample code.

Comment: Based on what you have shown, the second file will be created in root, not home. So you want `touch ~/2.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for testing it out. I just did some testing and it is consistent with part of your testing too. I will update in my own answer, so my findings don't get buried in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer to my own question. The $HOME environment variable does not exist at the time the user_data script is run.

I tried to 'echo $HOME >> /etc/a.txt' and I got a blank line. And instead of creating a file using 'touch $HOME/1.txt', I tried 'touch /home/ubuntu/1.txt' and the file 1.txt was created.

So, I can only conclude that $HOME does not exist at the time user_data was run.

----- Update 1 -----

Did some further testing to support my findings above. When I ran `sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME  > /etc/a.txt'`, it gave me the result of `/root` in the file `/etc/a.txt`. But when I ran `echo $HOME > /etc/b.txt`, the file `/etc/b.txt` contained 0xA (just a single linefeed character).

Did another test by running `set > /etc/c.txt` to see if $HOME was defined & $HOME didn't exist amongst the environment variables listed in `/etc/c.txt`. But once the instance was up, and I ran `set` via an SSH session, $HOME existed & had the value `/home/ubuntu`.

I also wondered who was running during the initialization so I tried `who am i > /etc/d.txt`. And `/etc/d.txt` was a 0-byte file. So, now I don't know which user is running during the EC2 instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is the default path used at `user_data` but I did a simple test and I found the solution to your problem.

In an EC2 Instance, I tried this in my `user_data`

```
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #! /bin/bash
    sudo bash -c "pwd > /var/www/html/path.html"
```

The result was this:

```
root@ip-10-0-10-10:~# cat /var/www/html/path.html
/
```

Did you check if you have this file created?

```
ls -l /2.txt
```

Feel free to reach me if you have any doubts.

Comment: As I've mentioned, I have no issues creating files in other directories. Any other directory seems to be fine except for $HOME.

Comment: Regarding your code, you are trying to create a file like this:
`touch 2.txt` so this file will be created at `/root/2.txt`
If you try to change your code and create the file like this:
`touch $HOME/2.txt`
You should have success. Can you try?

Comment: The `$HOME` variable exists! I tried and it works.

Comment: Really? It didn't work on my Ubuntu, or a Red Hat derivative. What did you do to determine that $HOME environment variable exists?

Comment: Try this at your `user_data`: `sudo bash -c 'echo $HOME"  > /var/www/html/path_home.txt'`

Comment: I did it using `echo $HOME >> /etc/file.txt` and I got an empty line. I was expecting to see `/home/ubuntu` when I opened the file.

Subsequently, I just hard-coded `/home/ubuntu/` as a prefix to all my various file creations in `$HOME` and it seemed to work.

Nuno: what Linux were you testing yours on?